# Is there a wordpress filter to edit the markup of inline images?

Tags: images, block-editor

I would like to add a class to wordpress inline images. Is there a filter that i can use to edit its markup?

[image: Inline image inside a paragraph block]

[image: code generated by wordpress for the inline image]

Answer (score 1):

You can click the vertical "..." menu > "Edit as HTML" and add your class there manually.

There is currently no other interface field to directly add a class to an inline image tag out of the box.

A plugin could overload the toolbox of the inline image, but currently only the width is editable.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to do it with add_filter, so that i do not have to do it every time?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of the block editor when it comes to expanding it. However, and for sure it's not as clean and it very much depends on your use case and logic, you could add some javascript in your theme to automatically add the desired class to all matching images with `jQuery('.your-selector img').addClass('.your-class');`. Of course, you may want more than this simple snippet to avoid jarring sudden style changes on page load.